# How can I enchant a bow with Infinity 1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I put the bow in the enchantment table and only *Power III* pops up.

I covered some bookshelves with torches (to get lower level enchantments) but still only was given *Unbreaking* and *Power* options.

I have all 30 bookshelves in the proper orientation.

Comment: On another note, you only need 15 bookshelves to get level 30 enchants for almost 3 years now (1.3.1)

Comment: I found out that the symbols in the enchanting table where the selection of enchantments are is part of the galactic alphabet. Transelate them, and you should be able to noticed which is which before you apply then enchantment. my source and proof: youtube.com/watch?v=fD317gMytAs

Answer (score 6):

Enchantments are completely random. There is no way to guarantee which enchantment you will get.

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting)

> The level requirement influences the quantity, type, and level of enchantments instilled in the item, with a higher experience level generally resulting in more and/or higher-level enchantments. **Nevertheless, there is a heavy random factor, and even a level 30 enchantment (the maximum) doesn't guarantee more than one enchantment, nor even that enchantments will be "maximum strength"** — a level 30 enchantment can still yield Fortune II or Efficiency III alone, for example.

If you don't want to waste enchantments on equipment, I would suggest trying to enchant books instead. This is slightly more resource intensive, but that way, later you can combine books in an anvil to get stronger enchantments, and even apply a specific set of enchantments of your choosing to the equipment you want to enchant.

---

**Post-Note:** I have actually found that if you are looking for a bow with the "Infinity" Enchantment *specifically*, you will actually have better luck with fishing.

- You can start off with an un-enchanted fishing rod; with luck you will eventually find a rod with the "Luck of the Sea" enchantment (Lowers chance of "junk" catches by 2.5% per level and increases chance of "treasure" catches by 1% per level)
- If you then use this, you have an increased chance of finding an enchanted bow - I personally have had *much* better luck of getting a bow with the "Infinity" enchantment this way.

Comment: +1 for the books. Yeah they're resource-intensive as they take 3 paper (9 Sugar Cane) + 1 leather, but both Cane and Cows are easily farmed and replacable compared to say, diamond tools, which are made from hard-to-find, non-renewable resources. Chances are if you've set up 30 bookshelves for enchanting you've already got the farms needed to make the books

Comment: @Robotnik I believe it's a 1:1 for paper:sugarcane. You still need 3 sugarcane but this will craft 3 pieces of paper

Comment: Ah true, I forgot that haha :)

Comment: I found out that the symbols in the enchanting table where the selection of enchantments are is part of the galactic alphabet. Transelate them, and you should be able to noticed which is which before you apply then enchantment. my source and proof: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fD317gMytAs

Answer (score 0):

You can also make an Enchanter, which is a darksteel stand with a book. Four darksteel, two diamonds and a book. Then all you need is a book and quill, plus one ender pearl and a level cost of 30 to make the infinity I book, then 6 more level cost to use the anvil to put the enchantment on your bow.

Comment: The question only specifies vanilla Minecraft, this method may be viable with mods (Feed the beast? Not sure what has "darksteel") but won't work for most people.